# Vaadin Convert and display image as PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext, vaadin, image-conversion

Does anyone know how image file can be easily converted into PDF format. What I need is to get the image from database and display it on the screen as PDF. What am I doing wrong?  I tried to use iText but with no results.
My code:

```
StreamResource resource = file.downloadFromDatabase();//get file from db
Document converToPdf=new Document();//Create Document Object  
PdfWriter.getInstance(convertToPdf, new FileOutputStream(""));//Create PdfWriter for Document to hold physical file 
convertToPdf.open();
Image convertJpg=Image.getInstance(resource); //Get the input image to Convert to PDF
convertToPdf.add(convertJpg);//Add image to Document
Embedded pdf = new Embedded("", convertToPdf);//display document
pdf.setMimeType("application/pdf");
pdf.setType(Embedded.TYPE_BROWSER);
pdf.setSizeFull();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Split it in two steps. Is the PDF generated correctly? The display it. (But why go via PDF to display a image, display the image directly would be more efficient

Comment: Why would you want to convert and image into a PDF? That would require the some users to have a PDF program installed. Surely displaying the image as an image will work in any browser?

Comment: Chris, the issue is tt when I display the image with Vaadin - its size (scale) is always browser- dependent. Firefox renders the image within the window width, while Chrome shows the same image as bigger and wider than the screen size. But I need to be sure tt image is always displayed in full width of the screen and is not cut by browser.

Comment: Thanks @Lena that makes sense. You could try getting the image to show correctly using CSS instead, or even by adding the image into a CustomLayout with HTML that will display the image how you want it.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using iText correctly:

1. You never close your writer, so the addition of the image never gets written to the outputstream.
2. You pass an empty string to your `FileOutputStream`. If you want to keep the pdf in memory, use a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. If not, define a temporary name instead.
3. You pass your `Document` object, which is a iText-specific object to your `Embedded` object and treat it like a file. It is not a pdf-file or byte[]. You'll probably want to pass either your `ByteArrayOutputStream` or read the temp file as a `ByteArrayOutputStream` into memory and pass that to `Embedded`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will use (Vaadin + iText)

```
Button but = new Button("FV");

    StreamResource myResource = getPDFStream();
    FileDownloader fileDownloader = new FileDownloader(myResource);
    fileDownloader.extend(but);

    hboxBottom.addComponent( but );


private StreamResource getPDFStream() {
    StreamResource.StreamSource source = new StreamResource.StreamSource() {

        public InputStream getStream() {

            // step 1
        com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();
        // step 2
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            try {
                com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);

                // step 3
                document.open();

                document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);   //Something like in HTML :-)

                document.add(new Paragraph("TEST" ));


                document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);   //Something like in HTML :-)                             

                document.newPage();            //Opened new page

                //document.add(list);            //In the new page we are going to add list

                document.close();

                //file.close();

                System.out.println("Pdf created successfully..");




            } catch (DocumentException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(WndOrderZwd.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = baos;
            InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray());
              return input;

        }
    };
  StreamResource resource = new StreamResource ( source, "test.pdf" );
    return resource;
}
```